# Windows 7 Asian-compatible console font?

Tags: fonts, console

I need to debug some kanji and kana (Japanese) in the console. They show up as blocks or '?' because the default console fonts do not support it.
Adding Asian fonts like Meiryo won't work because I think they don't meet these criteria:

- If it is not a TrueType font, the face name must be "Terminal."
- If it  is an Asian TrueType font, it must also be an Asian character set.

I can't seem to find a free font that is supported in the console. Or perhaps I do something else wrong?

I added the fonts via

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont
```

But they don't show up in the consoles properties window.
The key starts with 000 (adding a 0 for every font I add) and the string-value is the name of the font.

Comment: I guess windows console not support unicode .. ASCII only ..

Comment: http://qualapps.blogspot.nl/2011/01/display-unicode-in-windows-console.html Says that it does support unicode. But I need to use unicode in the console without programming somehow. Because the console itself it not created by me. Also, why would MS allow asian fonts in the console if it can't work with it?

Comment: Hey thanx .. you make know about chcp command .. about codepage ..

Comment: You need a compatible font first or it will still be blocks. Besides, the chcp command doesn't apply to Asian languages afaik.